# Mysql problems with using LOAD DATA to create millions of rows

Tags: mysql

I am building a php / mysql website that involves a table with more than 3 million rows. I am using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to import a 1.2gb .csv file and it is working for the most part but I have come across a few weird problems and would like to know if anyone has come across them before and if there's anything I should be doing differently.

Firstly, when I load in a .csv file with 3628446 rows (using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE). It goes in without a problem, but a SELECT COUNT(*) tells me that there are only 3606792, that's 21654 rows too few. However, when I delete all the rows in PhpMyAdmin it reports 3628446 rows deleted - the correct number of rows!

Second anomaly, it creates a row in the table that shouldn't exist - the first column contains the string "Row Count:" and the second column contains "3628445" - almost the correct number of rows! All the remaining rows are NULL. (It is an unusual table with no foreign keys and all columns accept NULL).

Is there anything I should know about this and has anyone else come across similar problems?

Comment: Don't worry phpmyadmin shows only an estimated. It is specially with bog numbers very faulty

Comment: @nbk I am afraid you are wrong

Comment: To be sure that all rows are inserted, export them and make a File compre, to see the difference. If there are rows that have faults

Answer (score 0):

The second anomaly is because you used count(*) that is why it returns a row with row count 
it can be verified use `SELECT count(*) as NumberOfRows` and it will show NumberOfRows in first column, to return proper number of rows the right syntax is `SELECT count(id) as NumberOfRows from Table_Name` which will return a single row with a single column with the name NumberOfRows, also check if it fixes the first anomaly.

Comment: "`SELECT count(*) as NumberOfRows` and it will show NumberOfRows in first column" - Do you have any reference for this statement?